# SQLITE_MISUSE when trying to execute select query in iOS xcode

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have a class to access to my database and when I want an instance, I call this function

```
 +(DatabaseHelper*) getInstanse
{
if (!instance) {
    instance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    [instance createDatabase];
}
return instance;
}
```

and here is `createDatabase` function

```
-(void) createDatabase
{
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:
                [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: databaseName]];
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        [self createTableProduct];
        [self createTableCategory];
        [self createTableState];
        [self createTableAgency];
        [self createTableNews];
        [self createTableKnowledge];
        [self createTableVideos];
        [self createTableProductComment];
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
    }
}

}
```

I don't have problem with create database and insert into it but when I want execute select query it says sqlite_misuse

Here is my select query

```
-(NSMutableArray*) getAllAgencies
{
[self createEditableDatabase];
NSMutableArray *agencies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *query = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@_%@", agencyTable, [Shares getLanguage]];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &statement, NULL);
if (sqlResult == SQLITE_OK)
{
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        int Id = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        char *nameChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        char *phoneChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
        char *addressChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
        char *faxChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4);
        char *emailChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5);
        char *detailsChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6);
        int stateID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 7);
        float latitude = (float) sqlite3_column_double(statement, 8);
        float longtitude = (float) sqlite3_column_double(statement, 9);
        NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:nameChars];
        NSString *phone = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:phoneChars];
        NSString *address = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:addressChars];
        NSString *fax = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:faxChars];
        NSString *email = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:emailChars];
        NSString *details = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:detailsChars];
        AgencyData *data = [[AgencyData alloc] init];
        [data setId:Id];
        [data setName:name];
        [data setPhone:phone];
        [data setAddress:address];
        [data setFax:fax];
        [data setEmail:email];
        [data setDetails:details];
        [data setStateId:stateID];
        [data setLatitude:latitude];
        [data setLongtitude:longtitude];
        [agencies addObject:data];
    }
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);

return agencies;
}
```

and here is createEditableDatabase function

```
- (void) createEditableDatabase {
// Check to see if editable database already exists
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDB = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"panberes.db"];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDB];
// The editable database already exists
if (success) return;
// The editable database does not exist
// Copy the default DB to the application Documents directory.
NSString *defaultPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"panberes.db"];
success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultPath
                               toPath:writableDB error:&error];
if (!success) {
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file:'%@'.",
              [error localizedDescription]);
}
}
```

i need some help

Comment: Can you explain show where/when you use `getInstance`? Also why are you attempting to create an editable database every time you use `getAllAgencies`? Surely in your `getInstance`, you need to copy/create editable database first, then create the tables inside. Final question where is the variable `database` defined and initialised? Are you opening it?

Comment: in my viewdidload i call get instance

Comment: i just write it to test if it solves the problem (createEditableDatabase)

Comment: it's inside @implementation DatabaseHelper

Comment: and i haven't any problem when i want insert into tables!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is after you create the database in the `createDatabase` method, you then close the database (`sqlite_close(database)`).  You never reopen the database to perform the sqlite query.  The method `[self createEditableDatabase]` only copies the editable database file if it doesn't exist in the first place, but it doesn't open the database.  Sqlite will throw a "MISUSE" error whenever you attempt to run a query and there is no open database.

Also, it's unclear in your code if `createDatabase` and `createEditableDatabase` are dealing with the same database.  If they are, it may be best to open the database and leave it open until you're done with it.  Opening and closing a database multiple times will cause a performance penalty.